# can't get all of excute file 's content

Tags: file, elf

First,sorry about my bad english.
I try to get content of excute file on linux.But there is a error.
instead of displaying all of content.It only display a part of them

Myfile is b.out :
quan@quan-desktop:~/quanrocktest/tuan1$ cat b.out
�ELFquan���0�4 4($!44�4�44�4�����
....
...
�4�44�4
etc...
b.out is an ELF file

Mycode :

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

#include "stdlib.h"

int main(){

```
    FILE *file;
    char *buffer;
    unsigned int fileLen;

    //Open file
    file = fopen("/home/quan/quanrocktest/a/b.out", "r");

    //Get file length
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    fileLen=ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    //Allocate memory
    buffer=(char *)malloc(fileLen+1);
    if (!buffer)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory error!");
                                fclose(file);
        return 0;
    }

    //Read file contents into buffer
    fread(buffer, fileLen, 1, file);
    fclose(file);
    printf("len is %d \n",fileLen);
    //Do what ever with buffer
    printf("%s",buffer);
    free(buffer);
```

return 0;
}

And result :
quan@quan-desktop:~/quanrocktest/a$ g++ init.c
quan@quan-desktop:~/quanrocktest/a$ ./a.out
 
len is 8256 

�ELFquan���@quan-desktop:~/quanrocktest/a$

a.out just display 
�ELFquan��� 
When i use vi or cat,b.out still display well

Comment: Cant read all the characters in your question. Could you edit the question, and make sure all chars are readable?

Comment: some characters is not show on screen,but it 's just an example.You could understand it as a character on my file.

Answer (score 0):

The `"%s"` format specfier to `printf()` is meant to be used with NUL-terminated strings.  Your call to `printf()` is thus stopping at the first NUL byte in the ELF image.

Comment: what can I do,use cout or another format for printf.I m a newbie :(

Comment: You could use `fwrite()` or `write()` to write out the contents of the buffer, instead of `printf()`.

Answer (score 0):

Using utilities is quicker way for a newbie than writing a program.

You should try *[nm(1)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?nm)*, *[objdump(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump)* or *[readelf(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/readelf)*. These utils have lot of options. They are for list the content of an executable or object file.

If you want to see the bare file content, you should use *[hexdump(1)](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/hexdump/)*, or *[ghex2](http://www.digipedia.pl/man/doc/view/ghex2.1/)* (it requires graphical system, like Gnome Desktop).

Good luck! Yep, another thing: if you don't know, why printf() works that way, I recommend you not to hack executables. You don't need it now.